# Windows 10 Lock Screen - Windows Spotlight - Launch Chrome for links

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, lock-screen, windows-spotlight

On the Windows 10 lock screen, set to Windows Spotlight, there are "text box" links that will give you more information about the image once you sign in. These links automatically launch Microsoft Edge rather than my default browser - Chrome. I have searched everywhere for a solution to this with no success.

I have already set Chrome as default and associated every file type Chrome can open but still opens Edge. If I go to the file/protocol associations for Edge, everything is unchecked except for URL: Microsoft Edge and URL: read. It won't let me uncheck these protocols although I have no idea if these are the culprit.

If I go to "Choose default apps by protocol", I cannot choose apps installed on my computer, but only choices are the current default app or Look for an app in the store.

Comment: Make sure the option isn’t hidden due to your Settings.  You can make the option appear invisible (white text on white text).

Comment: ["Choose another app" will appear in the same color as your taskbar.](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/88795-look-another-app-pc-disappeared.html) for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm not sure what "option" you are referring to.  My taskbar is black.

Answer (score 0):

Down load the Chrometana Pro Extention from google chrome and it will give you the instructions to download edge deflector from GitHub and this will do what you want

Comment: Perhaps you should have tested this yourself before providing an answer.  This just keeps edge from opening when clicking the link on the lockscreen.  it doesn't open chrome instead.

Comment: After installing the app, use Win-R to run something like microsoft-edge:https:https://google.com so that you get the prompt to pick an app for the microsoft-edge protocol.  After I did that once now the lock screen links open in Chrome.  I suspect before you do this step, the lock screen cannot show the app choice dialog so nothing opens like @ChrisL saw.

Answer (score 0):

While the answer didn't make the lock screen open the "more info link" in chrome. (Using Win-R to run something like microsoft-edge:https:google.com) as suggested by @integrator helped make the lock screen open the "more info link" in Microsoft edge which I am satisfied with.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).